# MAMP Local w/ Multiple Magento Stores

Tags: magento, localhost, mamp

I'm doing some development work on a Magento site network (multi-store install). What I'm trying to do is get my local MAMP install to pull all the "stores" that are a part of the install to their own virtual host on my machine.

```
Example:
siteA.local -> Site A
siteB.local -> Site B
siteC.local -> Site C

BUT all from the same local Magento install running through MAMP.
```

I've looked in the backend Config of Magento and I did change the URL and Cookie URL in the backend to my virtual hosts. But, still nothing. My hosts files has been adjusted accordingly as has my virtual hosts.

Is there a resource or article online that goes into setting up a multi-store Magento install locally? That would be perfect...

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track. Take a look at this article:

http://www.crucialwebhost.com/blog/how-to-setup-multiple-magento-stores/

It should provide you the information you need...

Answer (score 1):

For Magento 2 local multi-site installation on MAMP, try this tutorial:

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/multi-site/ms_apache.html

Adding the required `MAGE_RUN_CODE` and `MAGE_RUN_TYPE` parameters in the relevant box in the Apache pane.

[image]

I'm running MAMP Pro 5.2.2.